# How do I check a value of a variable in an xslt

Tags: code-behind

How do I check the value of a [MY_VARIABLE]. Basically what I am doing is replacing this variable in code behind by a html table which I generate dynamically.

My code behind

```
oRetHTML.Replace("[MY_VARIABLE]", oDataStringBuilder.ToString())
```

I want to check if the value is empty or not.

My XSLT

```
<xsl:when test="[MY_VARIABLE] != '' ">
```

This does not work because it is not the right syntax.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mithil: This is not clear. How did you declare that variable? Is a variable or a parameter? How did you pass such parameter?

Comment: Good point, @Alejandro. I gave an answer but now suspect that I might be missing something about the origin of the value that's relevant in this case.

Comment: It is a string which is being replaced in the code behind. The way I am using in the xslt is       
    <td class="print-datatext">[MY_VARIABLE]</td>
 and my codebehind replaces the value with the dynamic html table. Hope I made it clear. I am sorry its a big onfusing to explain.

Comment: @Mithil: It looks like you are preprocessing the stylesheet... I don't think is a good approach given that you can use another stylesheet to produce the final stylesheet. Or more simple, you could just pass this as parameter.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "code behind". When you do oRetHTML.replace(), what is in oRetHTML? Your stylesheet? The source document to which you apply your stylesheet? The output of the stylesheet?

Comment: I apologies if I am unclear. By code behind I meant backend. Let me try to explain. I have XSLT 1 and XSLT2. oRetHTML is a just a stringbuilder. What I am doing is...I have a report which is rendered using XSLT1 but which has different sections which is rendered using XSLT2. So I have [MY_VARIABLE],[MY_VARIABLE1],... and so on which are part of XSLT1 but are actually rendered using XSLT2 since the format for all the values is same. I know this is a little confusing. let me try to figure out the issue. I will post the answer when I get it. Thank you all for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
<xsl:variable name="MY_VARIABLE" select="some text"/>
```

Then:

```
<xsl:if test="not($MY_VARIABLE = '')">
    <!-- do something here -->
</xsl:if>
```